Litterae translatae
Something looks wrong here. The answer is 10-letters long.


████████████████████████████
█ █       █                █
█  █ █ ███ █████ ███████████
█   █ █  y█     █ █       ██
██ █ █ ███ █████ █ █ █████ █
█ █     █ █ █   █ █ █ █    █
█████  ███ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ ███
█ █         █ █ █   █   █ ██
██ ████ ██████ █ █████████ █
█   █y  y       █   y     ██
████ █ ███ ███████████████ █
█ █   █ █     █           ██
██ █ ███ █ ███ █ █████ ███ █
█ █   █ █       █   █ █   ██
██ █████ ███ █ █████ █ █ █ █
█ █ █   █y   y  █   █ █ █ ██
██ ███ █ █ ████  █ █ ███ █ █
█ █   █ █   █       █     ██
██████ █ ███ █ █ █y█████████
█       █   █ ███          █
 ██ ████ █ ███ █ █ █y███ █ █
█ █   █   █ █   █   █ █   ██
████ █ █ ███ █ █████  ██ █ █
█ █   █ █   █ █     ██    ██
████ ███ █████ █████ █   ███
█ █ █ █ █   █   █ █y y██   █
██   █   █   █ █   █ █ █   █
█████████████████████ ██████


The answer is:

 TRITHEMIUS.

Observations:

 • There are two gaps in the solid border of the grid.
 • There are long horizontal stretches, but not vertical ones.
 • there are large areas with a checkerboard pattern.
 • The answer has ten letters. There are ten yellow blocks.
 • The inner region is 26 blocks × 26 blocks.

So this is ...

 ... a maze, of course, but we need to rearrange the inner region by shifting the rows. The first inner row is unchanged. The second row is shifted to the left by one by removing the leftmost block and re-inserting it to the right. Each row is shifted one more block than the previous one.

 We get:



 The path shouldn't be hard to find.

The answer word ...

 ... is found by finding a path and converting each yellow block to a letter. There are several ways to do that. Taking the columns or rows as letter indices does not yield anything useful. But perhaps taking the original column before shifting? This gives us a pattern like so:



 This is the tabula recta.

Putting it all together:

 After finding the correct path and revealing the letters of the tabula recta under the yellow blocks, we get:



 The letters spell TRITHEMIUS and indeed, it was the monk "Johannes Trithemius who coined the term tabula recta.

